# Custom MessageBox with standard icons

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to show a message box with more details than what the standard WinForms `MessageBox` will allow. I'm going to just create a custom message box. However, I want to have access to the same icons that the standard MessageBox has.

How can I create my own message box but still use the default icons?

Comment: when you say more detail, what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @Werdna by "more details" I mean the MessageBox also has a custom link that launches another control. That link is hidden/shown depending on logged in user access rights.